# Dolibarr Projects Module: DB_ERROR_42803

Tags: php, postgresql, php-pgsql, dolibarr

Long story Short: I launched an EC2 instance on AWS to run Dolibarr v13, running PostgreSQL 12.4 on RDS, and Dolibarr itself on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. All DIY, not Bitnami’s AMI.

Once I started setting up modules on the web app's console, I got this:

```
Modules/Applications: user, societe, projet, import, export
Database type manager: pgsql
Latest database access request error: SELECT p.rowid as projectid, p.ref, p.title, p.fk_soc, s.rowid as socid, s.nom as socname, s.name_alias, s.code_client, s.code_compta, s.client, s.code_fournisseur, s.code_compta_fournisseur, s.fournisseur, s.logo, s.email, s.entity, p.fk_user_creat, p.public, p.fk_statut as status, p.fk_opp_status as opp_status, p.opp_percent, p.opp_amount, p.dateo, p.datee, COUNT(t.rowid) as nb, SUM(t.planned_workload) as planned_workload, SUM(t.planned_workload * t.progress / 100) as declared_progess_workload FROM llx_projet as p LEFT JOIN llx_societe as s ON s.rowid = p.fk_soc LEFT JOIN llx_projet_task as t ON p.rowid = t.fk_projet WHERE p.rowid IN (-1) GROUP BY p.rowid, p.ref, p.title, p.fk_soc, s.nom, p.fk_user_creat, p.public, p.fk_statut, p.fk_opp_status, p.opp_percent, p.opp_amount, p.dateo, p.datee ORDER BY p.title, p.ref
Return code for latest database access request error: DB_ERROR_42803
Information for latest database access request error: ERROR: 42803: column "s.rowid" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function\nLINE 1: ...T p.rowid as projectid, p.ref, p.title, p.fk_soc, s.rowid as...\n ^\nLOCATION: check_ungrouped_columns_walker, parse_agg.c:1409
```

I can’t find anyone else seeing this on the usual sites, but I can’t be the only one. How do I fix this? I’m not well versed in PHP, so I’m not sure where to find the line of code trying to access my DB.

Comment: Sounds like you should file a bug report with whatever creates that incorrect SQL statement.

Comment: Good idea. Will do.